# Multiple references pointing to the same string?

Tags: vb.net, reference

Is the following simplification possible in the VB.NET?

Example: `text` variable pointing to another string:

```vb
Class Form1
    Sub New()
        Dim text As (what_type?) = AddressOf TextBox1.Text  'simplification
        If text = "foo" Then text = "bar"  'actually accessing TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think it is not possible, but I can be wrong.

Comment: This sort of thing isn't really possible in .NET - it uses _references_, not _pointers_.  The CLR can and does move things around; `TextBox1` (and it's properties, ie `Text`) could be moved somewhere else in memory at a moment's notice.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @dbasnett - better readability and maintainability of 4+ occurrences of something like `ImageOutputDirectoryTextBox.Text` in body of an event handler.

Comment: @JamesThorpe – so you say the same applies to C#? (i.e. this simplification can't be made even in the C#?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET doesn't have pointers. You can use [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx):

```
Public Property Text As String
    Get
        Return TextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        TextBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

You can use properties as layer to not expose the control itself but only relevant informations:

```
If Text = "foo" Then Text = "bar"
```

On this way you could even change the control(f.e. to `Label`) without breaking code.

Another approach is using a [lambda expression:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

```
Dim setText = Sub(str As String) TextBox1.Text = str
setText("test")
Dim getText = Function() TextBox1.Text
Dim text As String = getText()
```

Comment: I see this works procedurally, reading `TextBox1.Text` every time. But I'd like to keep local scope. So what about pointer to the same string as in C language?

Comment: @miroxlav: no, that's not possible. Thank goodness, you don't have pointers in VB.NET.

Comment: @miroxlav there's no pointers in vb.net managed code. On top of that, string are immutable.

Comment: Okay, I can still use set of local methods (inside `Sub()` or `Function()`) when wanting to avoid a property: `Dim text As Func(Of String) = Function() TextBox1.Text` (+ `Sub()` for setting the value)

Comment: @miroxlav: yes you could use a lambda, edited my answer

Comment: Thank you, I've added lambdas into separate answer in meantime, but I think I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

#### In local scope:

Using locally declared function and procedure (any of them is optional):

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Sub New()

        Dim text As Func(Of String) = Function() TextBox1.Text
        Dim setText As Action(Of String) = Sub(value) TextBox1.Text = value

        If text() = "foo" Then setText("bar")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You could just use the property as mentioned in the other answer, and mark it as `private`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe – sure I would if I neded the reference in multiple methods. But if I need it only in single method, I think it can be sometimes better to avoid extra properties.

Comment: Personally, this looks more confusing. If you just need it for one method. You could always use [With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: @the_lotus – yup, `With` is another viable option which no one mentioned so far :)  Its downsides are extra level of code indentation and possibility to have substution only for one object at time. But perhaps this can help some readers in their specific case.